# How enter only four value in text field from keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I am making an application in which  i want to enter only numeric value. So i choose number pad type keyboard. Now i want that when user click on text filed and enter numeric value then enter only 0,1,2 and 3 not anything else. What i will do for that so i can apply restriction on text-field's value? And enter only single value not double value ie 11.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

}

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 3):

If rhe values are that restricted, you should try using a picker view or slider as the input view of the field.

How are you going to communicate to the user that 60% of the buttons on the numeric keypad are visible, enabled, tappable, but will do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

in  `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` You can then check the character the user just entered for validity, returning NO for any invalid characters.

Here is a code sample to limit the size of a UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  if ([[textField text] length] + [string length] - range.length > MAX_LENGTH) {
    return NO;
  } else {
    return YES; 
  }
}
```

also see [this](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/defining-legal-input-character.html)